# The probability density function of half-chi-square distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, density-function, chi-squared-distribution

Let $X$ be a random variable from a chi-square distribution with 1 degree of freedom. The probability density function (pdf) of $X$ is $f(x) = \frac{\exp{(-x/2)}}{\sqrt{2\pi x}}$, $x>0$.

In the case of half-chi-square distribution with 1 degree of freedom ($\frac{1}{2} \chi^{2}_{1}$), is the pdf provided by $\frac{1}{2}\frac{\exp{(-x/2)}}{\sqrt{2\pi x}}$?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a useful general result.

> **Theorem.**
>   Suppose $X$ is a random variable with cumulative distribution function $F_X$, let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $b > 0$, and let $Y = a + b X$.
>
> 1. The cumulative distribution function of $Y$ (call it $F_Y$) is given by
>      $$
>    F_Y(y) = F_X\left(\frac{y - a}{b}\right)
>    $$
>      for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$.
> 2. If $X$ is also continuous with density $f_X$, then the density of $Y$ (call it $f_Y$) is given by
>      $$
>    f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{b} f_X\left(\frac{y - a}{b}\right)
>    $$
>      for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Your question is the special case where $X \sim \chi^2_1$ (whose density you know), and you're interested in the density of $Y = \frac{1}{2} X$ (here $a = 0$ and $b = 1/2$).
The theorem above will allow you to compute the density of $Y$.

> **Proof of 1.**
>   Just compute:
>   $$
> \begin{aligned}
> F_Y(y)
> &= P(Y \leq y) \\
> &= P(a + b X \leq y) \\
> &= P\left(X \leq \frac{y - a}{b}\right) && \text{(*)}\\
> &= F_X\left(\frac{y - a}{b}\right).
> \end{aligned}
> $$
>   (*) Here we used the assumption that $b > 0$. If $b < 0$, the inequality would change direction, and if $b = 0$, we wouldn't be able to divide by $b$ at all.
>
> **Proof of 2.**
>   Differentiating the result of the first part, we get
>   $$
> \begin{aligned}
> f_Y(y)
> &= \frac{d}{dy} F_Y(y) &&\text{(**)}\\
> &= \frac{d}{dy} F_X\left(\frac{y - a}{b}\right) \\
> &= \frac{1}{b} F^\prime_X\left(\frac{y - a}{b}\right) &&\text{(chain rule)}\\
> &= \frac{1}{b} f_X\left(\frac{y - a}{b}\right). &&\text{(**)}
> \end{aligned}
> $$
>   (**) Here we used the fact that a density of a continuous random variable is the derivative of that random variable's cumulative distribution function, which is a consequence of the definition of the density and the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: You  might want to re-emphasize the $b>0$ assumption since it is critical to both parts 1. and 2.

Comment: @DilipSarwate good suggestion; I've updated my answer